# QLineEdit emits returnPressed when getting focus triggered by other returnPressed singal

Tags: qt, qpushbutton, qlineedit, qdialog

I've 2 QlineEdit and a QPushbutton

```
QLineEdit *field1 = new QlineEdit();
QLineEdit *field2 = new QLineEdit();
QPushButton *button = new QPushButton();
```

What I want:

- If the user presses return in field1 the focus shall be changed to field2.
- If the user presses return in field2 the button shall be clicked.

For this I have:

```
/* A */ connect(field1, &QLineEdit::returnPressed, field2, QOverload<>::of(&QLineEdit::setFocus));
/* B */ connect(field2, &QLineEdit::returnPressed, button, &QPushButton::click);
/* C */ connect(submit, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &SomeClass::SomeFunction);
```

What happens now is:

1. If I press return in field1, focus goes to field2, but button emits clicked().
2. If I press return in field2, button emits two times clicked().

For point 1 I can assume that the return key pressed event is still active after setting the focus to field2. Is there a way to avoid this? But if this is the case why the button only emits once the clicked() and not twice like in the next step?

Point 2 can be solved if i replace connect B with

```
/* B */ connect(field2, &QLineEdit::returnPressed, button, &QPushButton::toggle);
```

Then clicked() is emitted only once. But this is not clear to me. [toggle() should only work for checkable buttons](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#toggle), but the [button is not checkable](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#checkable-prop). And also clicked() should [not be emitted if toggle() is called](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked).

Do I misunderstand these concepts?

I'm using Qt 5.12.9

#### Update

During writing I tested a bit around and changed the parent object form QDialog to QWidget which solves my problems. So I assume that hitting return on a QDialog somehow clicks the button. Maybe anyone can explain it to me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QDialog` has a default button that is triggered on Return pressed.
That why you always have an extra `clicked()` in both cases.

[QDialog default button](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#default-button)