# How to force keyboard focus on a specific widget/QGroupBox (PyQt5)?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm developing a GUI, and I have the issue that sometimes, hitting the 'enter' key makes several widgets send their signal. The weirdest part is that sometimes it happens, and sometimes not. The main thing is, I can't guarantee the focus on one and only one `QGroupBox` at all times.

Here is a somewhat minimal example. If you run it and enter text, then hit 'enter', two functions will be executed (image below).

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QComboBox, QStyleFactory, QDialog, QTextEdit,
                QGroupBox, QLabel, QLineEdit, QGridLayout, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout)
import sys


class GrblGUI(QDialog):

    class PositionDescriber:
        """ Label and widget associated for each axis. Save some writing later """
        def __init__(self, labelText, initVal=0.0):
            self.posLabel = QLabel(labelText)
            self.value = initVal
            self.posWidget = QLineEdit(str(self.value))


    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """ Initializes the GUI and all widgets within.
            Creates the general layout
        """
        super(GrblGUI, self).__init__(parent)
        self.originalPalette = QApplication.palette()

        self.axes = [ self.PositionDescriber("X pos : "),
                     self.PositionDescriber("Y pos : "),
                     self.PositionDescriber("Z pos : "),
                     self.PositionDescriber("A pos : "),
                     self.PositionDescriber("B pos : ")]
        self.size = range(len(self.axes))
        self.ports = ["None"]

        # Creating widget within panels
        self.createConnectToCOM()
        self.createPositionControlPanel()
        self.createPushButtonsPanel()
        self.createMessageHistory()

        mainLayout = QGridLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.connectToCOM, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.positionControlPanel, 1, 0)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.pushButtonsPanel, 0, 2, 2, 1)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.messageHistory, 1, 1)

        mainLayout.setRowStretch(1, 1)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.setWindowTitle("minimal")
        QApplication.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('Fusion'))
        QApplication.setPalette(QApplication.style().standardPalette())


    """
    Creation of panels, widgets, and associated layouts
    """

    def createConnectToCOM(self):
        self.connectToCOM = QGroupBox()
        self.availableDevicesScroll = QComboBox()
        for item in self.ports:
            self.availableDevicesScroll.addItem(item)

        connectLabel = QLabel("Connect to device :")
        self.updatePushButton = QPushButton("Update")
        self.updatePushButton.setDefault(True)
        self.connectPushButton = QPushButton("Connect")
        self.connectPushButton.setDefault(True)
        self.updatePushButton.clicked.connect(self.updateAvailableCOM)
        self.connectPushButton.clicked.connect(self.connectToPort)

        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(connectLabel, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.availableDevicesScroll, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.updatePushButton, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.connectPushButton, 1, 1)
        layout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        self.connectToCOM.setLayout(layout)


    def createPositionControlPanel(self):
        self.positionControlPanel = QGroupBox("Position Control Panel : ")
        for i in self.size:
            self.axes[i].posWidget.returnPressed.connect(self.registerInput)

        layout = QGridLayout()
        for i in self.size:
            layout.addWidget(self.axes[i].posLabel, i, 0)
        for i in self.size:
            layout.addWidget(self.axes[i].posWidget, i, 1)

        sendPushButton = QPushButton("Send to pos")
        sendPushButton.setDefault(True)
        sendPushButton.clicked.connect(self.sendToPos)
        layout.addWidget(sendPushButton, len(self.axes), 2, 1, 2)
        layout.setRowStretch(6, 1)
        self.positionControlPanel.setLayout(layout)


    def createPushButtonsPanel(self):
        self.pushButtonsPanel = QGroupBox("Things you may want to do : ")

        self.homingPushButton = QPushButton("Homing")
        self.homingPushButton.setDefault(True)
        self.homingPushButton.clicked.connect(self.homing)

        recPosPushButton = QPushButton("Record current pos")
        recPosPushButton.setDefault(True)
        recPosPushButton.clicked.connect(self.recordPosition)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.setSpacing(20)
        layout.addWidget(self.homingPushButton)
        layout.addWidget(recPosPushButton)

        layout.addStretch(1)
        self.pushButtonsPanel.setLayout(layout)

    def createMessageHistory(self):
        self.messageHistory = QGroupBox("Message history : ")
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.textEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.textEdit.setPlainText("")
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.messageHistory.setLayout(layout)


    """
    Methods to call
    """

    def connectToPort(self):
        self.textEdit.append("connectToPort")

    def updateAvailableCOM(self):
        self.textEdit.append("updateAvailableCOM")

    def registerInput(self):
        self.textEdit.append("registerInput")

    def homing(self):
        self.textEdit.append("homing")

    def recordPosition(self):
        self.textEdit.append("recordPosition")

    def sendToPos(self):
        self.textEdit.append("sendToPos")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    gallery = GrblGUI()
    gallery.show()
    app.exec()
    # sys.exit(appctxt.app.exec())
```

And the result after entering text:

[image: Screen after writing some text and hitting enter once]

I've tried different thing such as `setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)` or `setFocus()`, but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Related to [QLineEdit emits returnPressed when getting focus triggered by other returnPressed singal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64278289). In short, QDialog automatically *clicks* the current *default* button (which is chosen autonomously unless explicitly set). Note that calling `setDefault` on multiple buttons is pointless, since obviously there cannot be "multiple default buttons". Can you clarify why you tried to do that?

Comment: Besides that, for future reference try to create *more* minimal examples: your code has a lot of function calls and unnecessary elements, the error can be reproduced using a single line edit and one button. Also, `self.size` is an existing dynamic property of all QWidgets, you should not overwrite it with something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from both the [`default`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#default) and [`autoDefault`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html#autoDefault-prop) properties of QPushButton in [combination with the usage of QDialog](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#default-button), and it has the following results

- if `autoDefault` is `True`, a button becomes a possible `default` button;
- the `autoDefault` property of a QPushButton is `False`, unless it is/becomes a child (even indirect) of a QDialog;

Events received by a widget that does *not* accept them are automatically propagated to its parent, up in the parenthood hierarchy, until one widget *does* accept it or the top level widget is reached.

QLineEdit by default *handles* the return key press, but does *not* accept it, which means that it knows that the key has been pressed (since it can emit the `returnPressed` signal) but will not handle, thus propagating it to the parent.

Considering the above, the unwanted behavior is that the key event is also received by the QDialog, so there are various possibilities, depending on the requirements.

### Use QWidget instead of QDialog

This is the easiest choice, but you might still need a QDialog for its features: the `exec` event loop, the `accepted/rejected` signals and result interface, or just to simplify the modality

### Set the `default` property to `False` for **all** buttons

Obviously, you can set the `autoDefault` property to `False` for each button, but an easier solution is to use a cycle that loops over all QPushButton instances, which should be implemented in an override that we know for sure that would be called, like `exec` or, maybe better, `showEvent`:

```
class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog)
    # ...
    def showEvent(self, event):
        super().showEvent(event)
        if not event.spontaneous():
            for btn in self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
                if btn.default():
                    btn.setDefault(False)
                if btn.autoDefault():
                    btn.setAutoDefault(False)
```

This can become a problem, though, as sometimes you might want to use that feature anyway: for instance, if you have a tab/stacked widget, and you want to avoid the return feature in a page that has a line edit, but not in another one that only has one button (like a wizard).

### Ignore the `Return` key in the dialog

Overriding the `keyPressEvent`, and call the base implementation *only* if the key is *not* return or enter (this has the same problem above, as it completely disable the feature):

```
class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog)
    # ...
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() not in (QtCore.Qt.Key_Return, QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter):
            super().keyPressEvent(event)
```

### Accept the key event in the line edit

This is probably a more appropriate approach, as it solves the problem at the *source*: consider the event as accepted in the QLineEdit if the return/enter key is pressed. This can only be done in a subclass:

```
class LineEdit(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        super().keyPressEvent(event)
        if event.key() in (QtCore.Qt.Key_Return, QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter):
            event.accept()
```

Answer (score 0):

As @musicamante found out, this is closely related to [QLineEdit emits returnPressed when getting focus triggered by other returnPressed singal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64278289/qlineedit-emits-returnpressed-when-getting-focus-triggered-by-other-returnpresse?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The simpliest answer was to inherit from `QWidget` instead of `QDialog`, as there won't be default buttons anymore.

Answer (score 0):

May be the use of `eventFilter` for whole form is the solution in your case:

1. `from QtCore import QEvent`
2. Define `eventFilter(self, obj, event)` in `class GrblGUI` and place under `Qt.Key_Enter` branch the callback you want for enter key press.
3. Register event filter `app.installEventFilter(gallery)`

Modified example below (be careful, I switched to PySide2 in example, you can easily switch back to PyQt5 again):

[image: App work example]

---

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QEvent # Step 1 - import QEvent
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QComboBox, QStyleFactory, QDialog, QTextEdit
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QGroupBox, QLabel, QLineEdit, QGridLayout, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout
import sys

class GrblGUI(QDialog):

    class PositionDescriber:
        """ Label and widget associated for each axis. Save some writing later """
        def __init__(self, labelText, initVal=0.0):
            self.posLabel = QLabel(labelText)
            self.value = initVal
            self.posWidget = QLineEdit(str(self.value))

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """ Initializes the GUI and all widgets within.
            Creates the general layout
        """
        super(GrblGUI, self).__init__(parent)
        self.originalPalette = QApplication.palette()

        self.axes = [ self.PositionDescriber("X pos : "),
                     self.PositionDescriber("Y pos : "),
                     self.PositionDescriber("Z pos : "),
                     self.PositionDescriber("A pos : "),
                     self.PositionDescriber("B pos : ")]
        self.size = range(len(self.axes))
        self.ports = ["None"]

        # Creating widget within panels
        self.createConnectToCOM()
        self.createPositionControlPanel()
        self.createPushButtonsPanel()
        self.createMessageHistory()

        mainLayout = QGridLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.connectToCOM, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.positionControlPanel, 1, 0)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.pushButtonsPanel, 0, 2, 2, 1)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.messageHistory, 1, 1)

        mainLayout.setRowStretch(1, 1)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.setWindowTitle("minimal")
        QApplication.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('Fusion'))
        QApplication.setPalette(QApplication.style().standardPalette())

    """
    Creation of panels, widgets, and associated layouts
    """

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event): # Step 2 - declare QEvent filter
        if event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:
            if (event.key() == Qt.Key_Enter or event.key() == Qt.Key_Return):
                self.textEdit.append("***DEBUG: Enter pressed")
                # Step 2 Place callback you want to process key press
                event.accept() # block event propagation to other widgets
                return True
        return False

    def createConnectToCOM(self):
        self.connectToCOM = QGroupBox()
        self.availableDevicesScroll = QComboBox()
        for item in self.ports:
            self.availableDevicesScroll.addItem(item)

        connectLabel = QLabel("Connect to device :")
        self.updatePushButton = QPushButton("Update")
        self.updatePushButton.setDefault(True)
        self.connectPushButton = QPushButton("Connect")
        self.connectPushButton.setDefault(True)
        self.updatePushButton.clicked.connect(self.updateAvailableCOM)
        self.connectPushButton.clicked.connect(self.connectToPort)

        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(connectLabel, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.availableDevicesScroll, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.updatePushButton, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.connectPushButton, 1, 1)
        layout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        self.connectToCOM.setLayout(layout)

    def createPositionControlPanel(self):
        self.positionControlPanel = QGroupBox("Position Control Panel : ")
        for i in self.size:
            self.axes[i].posWidget.returnPressed.connect(self.registerInput)

        layout = QGridLayout()
        for i in self.size:
            layout.addWidget(self.axes[i].posLabel, i, 0)
        for i in self.size:
            layout.addWidget(self.axes[i].posWidget, i, 1)

        sendPushButton = QPushButton("Send to pos")
        sendPushButton.setDefault(True)
        sendPushButton.clicked.connect(self.sendToPos)
        layout.addWidget(sendPushButton, len(self.axes), 2, 1, 2)
        layout.setRowStretch(6, 1)
        self.positionControlPanel.setLayout(layout)

    def createPushButtonsPanel(self):
        self.pushButtonsPanel = QGroupBox("Things you may want to do : ")

        self.homingPushButton = QPushButton("Homing")
        #self.homingPushButton.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus); #!!!

        self.homingPushButton.setDefault(True)
        self.homingPushButton.clicked.connect(self.homing)

        recPosPushButton = QPushButton("Record current pos")
        recPosPushButton.setDefault(True)
        recPosPushButton.clicked.connect(self.recordPosition)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.setSpacing(20)
        layout.addWidget(self.homingPushButton)
        layout.addWidget(recPosPushButton)

        layout.addStretch(1)
        self.pushButtonsPanel.setLayout(layout)

    def createMessageHistory(self):
        self.messageHistory = QGroupBox("Message history : ")
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.textEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.textEdit.setPlainText("")
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.messageHistory.setLayout(layout)

    """
    Methods to call
    """

    def connectToPort(self):
        self.textEdit.append("connectToPort")

    def updateAvailableCOM(self):
        self.textEdit.append("updateAvailableCOM")

    def registerInput(self):
        self.textEdit.append("registerInput")

    def homing(self):
        self.textEdit.append("homing")

    def recordPosition(self):
        self.textEdit.append("recordPosition")

    def sendToPos(self):
        self.textEdit.append("sendToPos")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    gallery = GrblGUI()
    gallery.show()
    app.installEventFilter(gallery) # Step 4 - register event filter in app
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't seem a valid solution: first of all, it prevents receiving the enter key by ***any*** widget (so, `returnPressed` will never be emitted for the line edits), and it also results in having the key filtered from *anywhere* in the application making it difficult to define the target.